# SuiteScript: How do you delete the result of nlapiSearchRecord?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I just want to delete the fulfillment request of a sales order if certain criteria is met.

This is what I've tried.  I know that I'm doing it wrong but I haven't found a lot of examples of how to actually use the results of the search.  Any help would be most appreciated.

```
var frId = nlapiSearchRecord('fulfillmentrequest', null, [
        new nlobjSearchFilter('createdfrom', null, 'is', nlapiGetRecordId()),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T')
], id);

nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', frId);
```

This is what I have landed on, unfortunately it doesn't actually work and I believe I will have to switch to a scheduled event because apparently the status will not get updated to "Closed" before the script runs even on an after submit function.

```
function frDelete() {
    if (nlapiGetFieldValue('Status') == "Closed"){
        var results = nlapiSearchRecord('fulfillmentrequest', null, [
                new nlobjSearchFilter('createdfrom', null, 'is', nlapiGetRecordId()),
                new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'),
                new nlobjSearchFilter('status', null, 'noneof', 'FftReq:F')
        ]);

        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', results[0].getId());
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', results[1].getId());
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', results[2].getId());
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', results[3].getId());
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', results[4].getId());
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', results[5].getId());
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', results[6].getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nlapiSearchRecord will return object.
nlapiDeleteRecord needs record's Type and Internal Id as a parameter.

```
var sFilters = [];
sFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('isinactive', null, 'is', 'F')); // you can add more filters.
var sColumns = [];
sColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('id')); // you can add more columns.
var sResults = nlapiSearchRecord('fulfillmentrequest', null, sFilters, sColumns);

var recordId;
if (sResults.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < sResults.length; i++) {
        recordId = sResults[i].getId();
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', recordId);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This works way better than what I did since mine tries to delete records that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`nlapiSearchRecord` returns an array of `nlobjSearchResult` objects, while `nlapiDeleteRecord` expects an integer for the id parameter.

You can retrieve the id from the search result with:

```
var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord(....);

if(searchResults.length) {
  var frId = searchResults[0].getId();
  nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', frId);
} else {
  // handle no results..
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve the problem I was having.  I've temporarily landed on a solution, which works when I put it in the console but I'm having a hard time getting it to work on after submit for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution.  This is a scheduled suitescript that will delete all Fulfillment Requests that are **New** or **In Progress** if the Sales Order they were created from is **Closed**, **Pending Billing**, **Billed** or **Canceled**.  None of these statuses can have remaining lines to be fulfilled so this makes sense to me.  I couldn't have done it without the help I received here though.

```
function frDelete() {
var results = nlapiSearchRecord('fulfillmentrequest', null, [
                new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'),
                new nlobjSearchFilter('status', null, 'anyof', 'FftReq:A','FftReq:B'),
                new nlobjSearchFilter('status', 'createdfrom', 'anyof', 'SalesOrd:H','SalesOrd:C','SalesOrd:G','SalesOrd:F')
                ]);
var recordId;
if (results.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        recordId = results[i].getId();
        nlapiDeleteRecord('fulfillmentrequest', recordId);
    }
}}
```